# Share Data Between Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to share data between component using service. But It not working as expected.

**Component**

```js
let myNum = 1;
sendChanges(myNum) {
    this.breadService.sendData$.next(myNum);
}
```

**Service**

```js
public sendData$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public setValue$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);
```

**Sibling COmponent**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.breadService.sendData$.subscribe(() => {
        this.breadService.setValue$.subscribe(data=>{
            this.id = data
            console.log(this.id);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you have redundant variable and subscription

**Component**

```
let myNum = 1;
sendChanges(myNum) {
    this.breadService.data$.next(myNum);
}
```

**Service**

```
public data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);
```

**Sibling component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.breadService.data$.subscribe((data) => {
        this.id = data
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have provided the same instance of breadService for both components

Answer (score 7):

Here `sendData$` is a Subject. Subscription callbacks to a Subject aren't executed till it emits a new value. So the inner subscription wouldn't be executed till a new value is pushed to `sendData$` after it is subscribed to. You could change the outer observable too to a `BehaviorSubject` to assign the value in the subscription immediately.

Service

```js
private sendDataSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
private setValueSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);

public set sendData(data) {
  this.sendDataSource.next(data);
}

public set setValue(value) {
  this.setValueSource.next(value);
}

public get sendData() {
  return this.sendDataSource.asObservable();
}

public get setValue() {
  return this.setValueSource.asObservable();
}
```

Also a subscription within a subscription isn't elegant. Pipe the outer observable.

Sibling Component

```js
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.breadService.sendData.pipe(switchMap(() => this.breadService.setValue))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.id = data
      console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but I got error on next `this.breadService.sendData.next(myNum);`

Comment: `Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'`

Comment: My bad. I forgot to add the setters. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You need to set the value using the statement `this.breadService.sendData = myNum;`. It is updated using the Typescript [accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors).

Comment: it is problem because of the position file service?

Comment: when I add `data = 0;` in bred.service.ts. It just come out `0`