# Data sending between components doesn't work

Tags: angular

I have 2 components and I'd like to send the value of a string from one to the other. I have no idea why it is not working.

This is how I did it:

Component 1 (from):

```
export class UsersComponent {
  constructor(
      private cvPage: CvPageComponent
    ) {}
  onSubmit(){
    this.cvPage.cvData = doc.output("datauristring");
  }
}
```

The `doc.output` gives a string. The `cvPage` components is in the providers in the `app.module.ts` too. After this functions opens the other component.

Component 2 (to):

```
export class CvPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public cvData: any;

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.cvData);
    }
}
```

In the console I can see, that the variable remains `undefined`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: A quick way would be setup a singleton service and share the data through it between components. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxv2fq) You can do it with service if not related components, using `@Input` if parent child component. In demo both of them are avaible .

write service like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("default message");
  sharedParam = this.paramSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeParam(param: string) {
    this.paramSource.next(param)
  }

}
```

in component pu this service in costructors

```
constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }
```

then in first component set like

```
 this._dataService.changeParam("your parameter")
```

and in second component read like

```
this._dataService.sharedParam.subscribe(param=>console.log(param))
```

---

but if you open in new tab than your way can be passing parameter with router

approuting.module.ts change to

```
 { path: "cv/:param", component: CvPageComponent },
```

then in users.component.ts

```
window.open(cvurl+'/'+your_parameter, "_blank");
```

in  csv.component.ts in costructor import

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

to read parameter from url

```
let param=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param');
```

Comment: I tried this version, but for some reason I always get the default message...

Comment: In demo it works then . If you create demo instackblitz and then I can see exact problem.

Comment: I uploaded the two components to a Drive folder : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-W9fg1caLb-AANbBULZTDQ56ZFGGFGWO?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated answer for new blank page use url routing method

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help! :)