# How to push/pass table data from one component to another in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular9

I want to push/pass data of table (itemName, Quantity, retailRate and totalQuantity , totalPrice ) to another component(getDataComponent) when I click button (pushData()) also navigate to receive.
I am not able to send table data in controller. Is this approach is good to send data from one component to another with navigation...

**HTML:** * send.html*

````
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm"
          *ngIf="secondTableData.length">
           <thead>
             <tr class="table-primary">
               <td># </td>
               <td>Item</td>
               <td>Quantity</td>
               <td>Price</td>
               <td class="pull-right">Action</td>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let newdata of secondTableData let i=index;">
               <td>{{i+1}}</td>           
               <td>{{ newdata.itemName }}</td>  <!--this data to push in receiveComponent -->
               <td class="text-center">{{ newdata.Quantity }}</td>   <!--this data to push in receiveComponent -->
               <td>{{ newdata.retailRate }}</td>  <!--this data to push in receiveComponent -->
              
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
           <tr class="table-secondary">
               <td>#: {{ secondTableData.length }}</td> 
               <td></td>
               <td class="text-center">TQ: {{  totalQuantity }}</td>   <!--this data to push in receiveComponent -->
               <td>TP: {{ totalPrice }}</td>   <!--this data to push in receiveComponent -->
               <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
     <div>
       <hr>
       <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"  (click)="pushData()">
           <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> OK
       </button>
      
     </div>
   </div>```

**Component.ts:** *sendComponent.ts*

   ```tabeTata:any 
       pushData(){
        let data:any = this.tabeTata.values;
        this.routerService.navigate(['./receive'],{
           queryParams:{data:JSON.stringify(data)}
        })
       }```

**receive.Html**  *here i am using random data for demo. I want to place received data to respective places*

   ```<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>SN</th>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Unit</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Total</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>Custom oil </td>
           <td>10</td>
           <td>34</td>
           <td>340</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>Digital illustraion </td>
           <td>12</td>
           <td>50</td>
           <td>600</td>
         </tr>
           <tr class="small" style="height: 10px;">
               <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
               <td>Gross Amount:</td>
               <td>1100</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="small">
               <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
               <td>Discount:</td>
               <td>100</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="small">
               <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
               <td>VAT</td>
               <td>30</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="small">
               <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
               <td>Net Amont</td>
               <td>1030</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
   ```

**receivecomponent.ts**

   ```data:any;
      ngOnInit(): void {
      // To get data from biling component
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params)=>{
        this.data = JSON.parse(params.data);
        console.log(params);
      })
    }```


**Any one is there to help, May be this one is complex**
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data sending between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188725/data-sending-between-components-doesnt-work)

Comment: This is not what i want

Comment: send data with state in router then

Comment: Can u please stackblitz please!!.. Is there is any way to pass data of table to controller?

Comment: @Sivakumar Tadisetti Do you have any solution of this? :-)

Answer (score 0):

try using `sharedService` between components.

here is an example of 'Component Intercommunication' through services:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-3?file=app%2Fside-bar%2Fside-bar.service.ts

For more information resd this article [**'3 ways to communicate between Angular components'**](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb)

Comment: This is not what i want.

Comment: What you seem to want Dany is not how it's done in Angular. In Angular data is communicated between components using Services.

Comment: It is possible to pass data  of Table (<td>) in controller? if yes then how ?

Comment: Angular is not HTML focussed, there should be no concept of "table data (<td>)" in your program. You have a Component class that should contain the data that you show in your table. The HTML is only there to display things and to generate user events that are passed to the Component. Then you pass that data to another component using a service.

Comment: You would pass the `component.secondTableData` to a service, and read that data from the other component.

Comment: How can i do that? @Robin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221099/discussion-between-dany-and-robin-de-schepper).