# Refresh one Component on click event of Another Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have 3 components in Angular-9 Application as shown below:

**Component 1**

```
<div>
   // I have a button here with Click Event.
</div>
```

**Component 2**

```
<div>
   // I have a Grid here. 
</div>

In a class file I'm getting Data and Binding Grid using ngOnInit() method.
```

And I'm using both Components in third component as below:

**Component 3**

```
<div id='third-component'>
    <component-one></component-one>
    <component-two></component-two>
</div>
```

I want to refresh the **Component2** data on click of a button that is there in **Component1**. How to do this?

Comment: You can use `rxjs Observable` on service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rxjs BehaviorSubject`.

First just creat a service called `data.service.ts` and in that create an `observable` of type `BehaviorSubject` and a function to push the value into that `BehaviorSubject`.

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

public notify = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

    public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
        this.notify.next(data);
    }
}
```

and in `component1.ts` `inject` that `service` and on button click just send `{refresh: true}` `object` in `notifyOther` `function` which will be subscribed by `component2` later.

```
refreshGridInAnotherComponent(){
    this.dataService.notifyOther({refresh: true});
}
```

and in your `component2.ts` you can `subscribe` from that observable on `component's ngOnInit` like this

`copmonet2.ts`

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.notifyObservable$.subscribe(res => {
          if(res.refresh){
              // get your grid data again. Grid will refresh automatically
              this.dataService.getData();
          }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to share data between angular components is: use an angular **service**

you can make the button from component1 trigger a function on the service

assuming that the data from component 2's grid also comes from the same service, once the data changes, the component refreshes automatically

this answer has a good example for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806447/4604645