# Refresh Component outside router outlet

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on Angular 12 and have a design where I have User data at the top (a header) and below there's a router outlet for my navigation. I have a tokenStorage which stores the user token in a indow session property. This works fine as by pressing F5 the user is still logged on.

Now my problem is the logout. When I'm removing the data of the token and press F5 the header is updated and the user data is not available anymore. So the remove of the user data itself seams also be ok.

But after logging out the header still itself shows the user data until I press F5. It lokks like the navigation only updates the router outlet but not the header. Trying to find a solution for explicitly refreshing the header I had no luck. Has anybody a hint or link where I can find a way to update components whcih are not part of the router outlet?

Best Regards

Parascus

Comment: your "header" should subscribe to a Subject in a service. When remove the data or add data, use `emit` to emit a value. See [Comunicate elements using a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service). I know that the title is "Parent and children communicate ...", but it's the way to comunicate two components that have no parent/child relation.

Comment: Hello Eliseo, thank you for the comment. With this information I managed to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `observables` to pass data among the components which are not related(parent-child). You can use `BehaviorSubject` to achieve your desired result. All you have to do is, upon clicking on `logout` you also have to pass some `data` or `boolean` property to your `BehaviorSubject`. And in your `header` component, you will subscribe to your `BehaviorSubejct` and in your subscription, whenever you will get the signal from `logout` then you can refresh the data or re-evaluate the date. I have answered something here

[Refresh one component from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498367/refresh-one-component-on-click-event-of-another-component-in-angular/64498640#64498640)